# How to save all image from the page using beautiful soup?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get all the image from the website and save it in my local using beautiful soup . I'm able to get only image available in the page not able to parse the image available after page refresh as i go down the page .

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
from time import sleep

html = urlopen('https://www.reddit.com/r/wallpapers/top/?t=all')
bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
images = bs.find_all('img', {'src':re.compile('.jpg')})
for image in images: 
    print(image['src']+'\n')
```

above is the code which I have written to perform this . it'll only parse few of the image in file not all of them

```
https://external-preview.redd.it/s7yoklHciONffazTYc70ba0zRV81F2FALn7wweilPbs.jpg?width=640&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=a88fa282e05b654928d8713d702a134ef72cbf46

https://external-preview.redd.it/gIdBuW-a4BIXktpScXUlwJysblF4-QcZ03KbUIa2UuI.jpg?width=640&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=baa49611bba27a8af223e805ea5419788b9e4487

https://external-preview.redd.it/SZracndjx4e_Yp1WRU-QzA400cdHcMsCMnE40M6v5u4.jpg?width=640&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=b6ab155357a23678e04116dc18ef72637960f311

https://external-preview.redd.it/_NeB4f9cyQBWVTV7s_O0tlC7-Z5Yomm0_J0h3l3wCbE.jpg?width=640&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=305a530f1f6dd7bf23d93bca2f15f16d6daf8aa0

https://external-preview.redd.it/NrD2CQ1PX2oF35bY7mwGiP2aIyDbYWpoV-6mFjUOlTo.jpg?width=640&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=2ca38c2776118e131f53b02802f02bf930ac0ff8

https://preview.redd.it/n1ci0trfgrey.jpg?width=640&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=81ca19c80ac05fda63202c8e2384db33ac5d72a7
```

so how can I able to parse many images from that page ?

Answer (score 0):

The additional content is not present without scrolling.

You could try mimicking any requests the page makes for additional image content when you scroll down. A quick peek in dev tab didn't yield anything that looked quick and easy to replicate in a robust manner.

I would probably go with Selenium and implement a method of scrolling to the bottom of the list then gather all the images at that point.

If you Google `python scrape reddit` there are a lot of examples. I assume on SO there already exists a scrolling reddit answer.